# Trouble with using globally defined variables: 'Use of undefined constant'

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have this code:

```
<?php

$db_initiallized = false;
$db_connection = NULL;

function db_init()
{
    global $db_initiallized, $db_connection;

    if(!$db_initiallized) //error occurs on this line
    {
        $db_connection = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
        if(!$db_connection)
        {
            echo 'Connection failure!';
            exit();
        }

        $db_initiallized = true;
    }
}

?>
```

And I get the error:

```
Use of undefined constant
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring.  Perhaps I am declaring global variables wrong.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array can be used instead:

```
$GLOBALS['db_initiallized'] = false;
$GLOBALS['db_connection'] = NULL;

function db_init(){

    echo $GLOBALS['db_initiallized'];
    echo $GLOBALS['db_connection'];
}
```

**OR**

If the variable is not going to change you could use [define](http://php.net/define).

```
define('db_initiallized', FALSE);
define('db_connection', NULL);

function db_init()
{
    echo db_initiallized;
    echo db_connection;
}
```

**OR**

If you have a set of functions that need some common variables, a class with properties may be a good choice instead of a global:

```
class MyTest
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function head()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }

    public function footer()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

$a = 'localhost';
$obj = new MyTest($a);
```

Comment: @user3361761 Solved your problem?